# How to parse JSON decimals correctly using ServiceStack JsonSerializer

Tags: c#, json, decimal, servicestack

I have the following scenario:

```
var json = "{\"AccruedInterest\":9.16666666666666E-6}";
var result = JsonSerializer.DeserializeFromString<MyResult>(json);
Assert.That(result .AccruedInterest, Is.GreaterThan(0m));
```

where `MyResult` declares the field `AccruedInterest` as a `decimal`

The above test sets `AccruedInterest` to 0 and consequently fails. If I set the JSON to anything other than an accrued interest value with an exponent then the test works.

Is the ServiceStack JSON handling of JSON string to decimals broken? The above appears to be perfectly valid JSON (using exponents etc.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you switch the type on your `MyResult` class to a `float` you will get the results you expect:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        const string json = "{\"AccruedInterest\":9.16666666666666E-6}";
        var result = JsonSerializer.DeserializeFromString<MyResult>(json);
    }
}

public class MyResult
{
    public float AccruedInterest { get; set; }
}
```

The reason for this can be found in [DeserializeBuiltin](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text/blob/e57f080847a4f87bf1be6e6c0e64fcc9cb571592/src/ServiceStack.Text/Common/DeserializeBuiltin.cs#L50-L51):

```
if (typeof(T) == typeof(decimal))
    return value => decimal.Parse(value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

If you try and do the parse yourself you will get an invalid format exception.

```
decimal.Parse("9.16666666666666E-6", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

If you specify a number style of float the exception will go away.

```
decimal.Parse("9.16666666666666E-6", NumberStyles.Float, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Likewise parsing it as a float works:

```
float.Parse("9.16666666666666E-6", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: That does indeed appear to work. It's not quite the answer I was looking for (is the decimal handling broken?) but the parsing to a float will work around this. Thank you!